# Import a image SRC with Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello I want to import an image in Javascript because I am making a game but I does not work. It works if I use a external link.

```
const src = "../img/image.jpg";
```

It does not work, someone know why?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This only creates a variable with a string value. You'd need to set a node's `.src` attribute or create a `new Image()` to do anything with this.

Comment: For one, that code does nothing. It sets a variable to the string "../img/image.jpg", so what else did you expect it to do and why would you expect it to do that?

Comment: all you are showing is that you defined src, const just provides a block scope variables and constants in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a variable with the string "../img/image.jpg" that happens to be named src this doesn't relate to images at all. We would need a lot more information to be able to help you. Like is the game in html? is the game in a canvas element? how are you wanting to use the image. Typically you can import/require a file depending on the js context.

try:

```
import image from "../img/image.jpg";
```

or

```
const image =  require("../img/image.jpg");
```

Comment: @MarceloAcevedo Remember to upvote the answer too